# How to detect you've reached the end of a fgets string of integers, when 0 is the last integer in the line, using c++?

Tags: c++, c, file, arr

If I'm reading in lines from a .txt file of varying length, (i.e. 5 integers on line 1, then 2 integers on line 2, then 10 integers on line 3, and etc.), using fgets (although I don't necessarily need to use it, just seemed like a good tool in my situation). Every solution I find returns an error of 0 (like strtol or atio).

```
char str[100];
char* p = str;
FILE* fp;
fp = open("text.txt",r);
if(fp == NULL) 
    printf("aborting.. Cannot open file! \n");
while(!foef(fp))
{
if(fgets(p,100,fp) != NULL)
{
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 20 ; j+=2) 
    {
        temp1 = strtol(p, &p, 10);
        // need to store temp1 into arr[j] if it is a valid integer (0->inf)
        // but should discard if we are at the end of the line
}
}
```

Comment: fp = open("text.txt",r); should be fp = fopen("text.txt",r);

Comment: Is there a newline character (`\n`) at the end of the string of integers also?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben's answer was so good, it should be part of the answer

Set errno to 0 before calling strtol.

Check errno. From man page

ERANGE

The resulting value was out of range.
The implementation may also set errno to EINVAL in case no conversion was performed **(no digits seen, and 0 returned)**.

Comment: Note that you'll not only need to check it, but reset it before the call to `strtol` you care about.  Otherwise you could see an error that occurred much earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use C++:

```
std::ifstream file("text.txt");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    int i;
    while (iss >> i) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The inner loop could simply load all of the ints into a vector directly or something:

```
std::ifstream file("text.txt");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::vector<int> all_the_ints{
        std::istream_iterator<int>{iss},
        std::istream_iterator<int>{}
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're throwing away the information available from `strtol`.

In particular, after a call

```
val = strtol(p, &endp, radix);
```

you are interested in whether `p == endp`.

In your call `strtol(p, &p, radix)` you're overwriting `p` too soon and losing the chance to perform the test.